# Working with matrix in R. Place an element in matrix

Tags: r

I have a distance matrix. For example :

```
d<-matrix(c(0,2,3,7,11,0,13,6,8,5,0,12,6,53,12,0), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
d
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0   11    8    6
[2,]    2    0    5   53
[3,]    3   13    0   12
[4,]    7    6   12    0
```

I want to create a neighbor matrix where distance is less than or equal to 5. In matrix nb, 1 indicates not a neighbor. However, they have no neighbor (excluding itself, for example, row 1 and row 4. I would like the one with the smallest distance to be their neighbor.

```
> nb=(d>=5)
> nb*1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    1
[2,]    0    0    1    1
[3,]    0    1    0    1
[4,]    1    1    1    0
```

Expected result

```
          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
    [1,]    0    1    1    0
    [2,]    0    0    1    1
    [3,]    0    1    0    1
    [4,]    1    0    1    0
```

I have tried and I don't know how to get it efficiently without using loop. This is just an example, my actual data has over 9000 rows. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: The question is not clear, isn't `6 > 5`? Exactly what do you mean by *However, they have no neighbor (excluding itself, for example, row 1 and row 4. I would like the one with the smallest distance to be their neighbor.*?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yes. 6 > 5. However, row 1 (city 1) has no neighbor which means that there is no other city that is within 5 miles from city 1. So I have to take the city with the smallest distance to be its neighbor. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following function does what you want.

```
fun <- function(Dist, n = 5){
  nb <- (Dist > n)*1L
  for(i in seq_len(nrow(nb))) {
    tmp <- Dist[i, ]
    tmp[tmp == 0] <- Inf
    nb[i, which.min(tmp)] <- 0L
  }
  nb
}

fun(d)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    0    1    1    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    1
#[3,]    0    1    0    1
#[4,]    1    0    1    0

fun(d, 10)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    0    1    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    1
#[3,]    0    1    0    1
#[4,]    0    0    1    0
```